# How to run my android app in my huawei honor(Hol-U19) Mobile?

Tags: android, debugging, android-virtual-device

I need to run my android app in my huawei honor Hol-U19(6999 rs) mobile, but it is not detecting when i tried to run my app in this device.Already i tried so many ways and tried to install several software related to hauwei poratal.It is detecting in my computer, but when try to run in android studio it id not detecting in AVD manager. How to install driver software for this mobile? Where we will get that software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Mobogenie3.......,install Mobogenie3 in your computer and turn debugging option on in your huawei Hol-U19,it will surely detect your device........

Hope it helps..!